# Integrating Google Adsense in AngularJS Application

Tags: angularjs, seo, adsense

I am working on an AngularJS application and trying to integrate Google Adsense to it.
I have been trying to do that for 3 months now.

Link to the website : http://www.curioussbox.com

After submitting the website on Google Adsense I get below message from them

[image]

Does the website really need more content or Google Adsense is unable to crawl the website because it's written in AngularJS? Or do I have to make the website more SEO friendly? According to my research, AngularJS application need to have "#!" in their URLs for Google and Bing to crawl. We have already done that.

The frustrating part is, I could not find any support number to contact them and find the real reason why the website is getting disapproved.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much text on your website; There's just a list of questions.

That doesn't provide enough information for the crawler to ascertain what the website is about.

Maybe create a landing page giving an introduction to the site and explaining what it is about.

Comment: I don't know why my answer was downvoted; I still think it's the correct answer.

They disapproved your account for the reason they gave you in their response.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your answer. Even my question was downvoted. Is there any way to find out who did it?